# Handling spam user profiles without deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spam

I run a site which allows users to create profiles, which naturally attracts SEO spammers trying to push their own links. I'm developing a one-click admin system to banish these profiles (but keep the details recoverable in case of error) - which approach below would be considered 'best practice' (if any)?

1) Create a copy of the `users` model (e.g. `banned_users`) and move banned users across to this model so that their accounts are disabled

2) Add a `banned_user` flag to the user profile and add a callback to every user action which checks whether the field returns true

My instinct says that 1 is cleaner - is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, given your described requirements, I would use option 2 (toggle a 'banned' flag to true).  It seems cleaner to me because:

- It's easier to un-do if a user is mistakenly banned
- Doesn't require multiple reads/writes from your database.
- You can run queries on all users (banned or not) without joining multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks Donovan. Do you believe the benefits of relieving the read/writes outweighs the insertion of logic (an if statement, I guess) on every show controller?

Comment: Generally speaking? Yes. A Boolean check doesn't add much overhead, but of course it depends on your app and what you're requirements are for that data. Run some benchmarks if you're concerned.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, this is the approach I took and it appears to be working well. Appreciate the help.